# ActionBar not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need some guidance regarding the working of Action bar. Actually clicking on a Action bar `MenuItem`. Current activity must be moved to another activity. But it's doing nothing. Not even any error. I used following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mnew1, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.home:
            try {
                openSearch();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

private void openSearch() throws IOException{
    val=address(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    Intent intnt=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SendSms.class);
    intnt.putExtra("loct", val);
    startActivity(intnt); 
}
```

Comment: clicking on which action bar button?

Comment: means you have taken one item with R.id.home id?

Comment: yes..i  used only one button

Answer (score 0):

Use `MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();`

And if you are using android home button then the id is `android.R.id.home`. In that case make sure you have `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` in your `onCreate`.

EDIT- Make sure you have imported these:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
```

Comment: It's simple. Remove all your imports. Then press ctrl+shift+o.

Comment: @user3101598 Hey, are you using ActionBarSherlock in the first place?

Comment: i didn't get what are you trying to say

Comment: Post your whole `Activity` and `mnew1.xml`.

Comment: just answer a simple question is it possible to get current location in one activity and passing address from there to another activity

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You may want to explain what does `val=address(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());` do?

Comment: i have pasted my full code at with few modification..please have a look..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609847/current-location-from-latitude-and-longitude noredirect=1#comment30852843_20609847

Answer (score 0):

put this code inside onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_main_activity_xml);

    // creating Actionbar
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.show();
    ...

}
```

and then put this code outside onCreate :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.mnew1, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle presses on the action bar items
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.home:
        try {
            openSearch();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void openSearch() throws IOException{
val=address(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
Intent intnt=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SendSms.class);
intnt.putExtra("loct", val);
startActivity(intnt); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is perfect. There is not any problem with this code. Actionbar button was not working due to null value it is receiving..and null value was just because of some hardware issues..nothing wrong with this code thanks